# Adding comments with pdfcomment without affecting the text

Tags: pdfcomment

I add comments to my PDF using the great [`pdfcomment`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) package.

When I add a comment using `\pdfcomment[avatar=notes]{comment}`, the comment icon changes the layout of the other text in the document. I would like the comments to be "above" the document, i.e., so that the document is set out the same whether the comments are included or disabled.

Is this possible? I can't find any settings or commands in the package user manual which describe this.

Comment: Are you in draft or final mode?

Comment: What you describe should at least be the default for PDF text annotations (`\pdfcomment`). You should add a MWE showing the problem.

Comment: I am in draft. My understanding is in final, the annotation would disappear completely. I would like the annotation icon to appear, but not move the text layout that I am annotating. I will try final to check and an give an MWE.